# How to make anime/toon like 2D Glow Particle Shader, Blender 3.3 eevee

Tags: uv, shaders, eevee-render-engine, procedural

[image]

I'm going to make a shader with the same image as above.

But I don't know how to organize mesh and UV, and how to implement glow and color.

What method should I use?

[image]

It was being made like this, but it's also very difficult to express sharply whether it's a mesh problem.

The example image above has a random size, depth, in a procedural form.